# C++ inheritance size with empty derived class object

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class base {
 int arr[10];
};
class b1: public base { };

class b2: public base { };

class derived: public b1, public b2 {};

int main(void)
{
    cout << sizeof(derived);
    return 0;
}
```

Since in c++ by default the members of class are private why does the sizeof derived class is 80.

Comment: How `sizeof()` is related to if members are private or not?

Comment: because they can't be inherited right ? why would there be space allocated to them

Comment: what else did you expect and why? why should private data not count for the size?

Comment: 1) So, are you saying, that if a variable is `private`, it doesn't need memory to be stored in? 2) "_because they can't be inherited right ?_" There is a subtle difference between "being inherited", and "being accessible from inherited classes".

Comment: just because you cant access them (in the derived) does not mean that they are not there

Comment: Private affects visibility. It does not affect the size of the class. 4 * 10 * 2 == 80.

Comment: Recall you can access the `base`-class subobject of `b1`, and you can access both the `b1` and  `b2` base-class subobjects of `derived`. All this stuff has to actually exist even if you're not permitted to touch the `arr` member directly.

Comment: "because they can't be inherited right ?" wrong, they are inaccessible from derived but does not mean they are not there

Comment: @VineetBhikonde "it needs to be stored but why should be accounted for sizeof the derived class" `sizeof` measures the size of the entire class, not "_sizeof (class) - sizeof(base classes)_".

Comment: okay thanks i got it.

Comment: Note that you inherit from `base` twice and so have two copies of `base::arr` to store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access-specifier `private` is only related to the accessibility of the members of the base class in the derived class. The derived class contains the sub-objects of the classes it derives from. In this case, it contains `b1`  and `b2` sub-objects. So its size is the sum of both their sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Your line of argumentation is flawed. Privacy has nothing to do with `sizeof` a class.

Consider this example:

```
class base {
    int value = 42;
public:
    int get() { return value; } 
};

class derived : public base {};
```

The `derived` does inherit the `get`, it has no (direct) access to `value`, but of course in a `derived` instance there is the member `value`. You can easily convince yourself by calling `get()` on a `derived` ;)

Answer (score 1):

`derived` inherits both `b1` and `b2`, so its size is at least the sum of their sizes, each one of them being at least size of ten `int`s, 40 bytes with 32bit `int`s. Which gives us at least 80. Member visibility is not relevant here, it does not affect type's size. Apparently, arrays can't be optimized out for `derived`, being publicly a `base` (twice!), should contain exactly as many subobjects of type `base`—otherwise how would you upcast it to `base`?

Comment: i just thought that since it's a private variable it's not visible directly and it would just be stored with the base class.

Comment: Yes, it is. It is a member of a subobject of base class, this subobject being a part of any instance of `derived`.